# Join Last Record Based on TimeStamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have a access log, which records usernames and a timestamp at various points in the application. I want to see if I can approximate the amount of time they are spending in the application. Basically I want to join each record to the last access record based on the timestamp, so I can figure out the time difference.

I can't think of how to join to the first record whose timestamp is less than the current record. What is the way to do this?

Comment: What database engine and version are you using?

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. MS-SQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT A.UserName, A.EntryDate, DATEDIFF(ss,A.EntryDate, B.EntryDate) SecondsDuration
FROM YourTable A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(EntryDate) EntryDate
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE UserName = A.UserName AND EntryDate < A.EntryDate) B
```

Comment: This appears to work, thanks. I'll have to read up about apply, i've never used that one before.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't think of how to join to the first record whose timestamp is less than the current record. What is the way to do this?

You almost gave yourself the answer:

Something similar to below should work:

```
SELECT
   lt.*,
   lastentry.timeofEntryColumn,
   DATEDIFF( second, lt.timeofEntryColumn, lt.timeofEtnryColumn) AS DifferenceinSeconds
FROM logTable lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN logtable AS lastentry
ON lastentry.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM logtable lt2
          WHERE lt2.timeofEntryColumn < lt.timeofEntryColumn
          ORDER BY lt2.timeofEntryColumn desc)
```

Of course, you should add some more to this: maybe a condition to the outer join that requires the userID match...

Comment: How would I add the condition to select the last entry from the same user? This just finds the time difference to the last entry. How can I add that condition into the subquery?